# Sencha GXT Grid filters are slow. Can I make them fast?

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I'm using GXT Grid with a filter (StoreFilterField to be exact).
The problem is that when filter changes (user types something or clears it) it takes a long time for Grid to refresh.

I have a relatively small grid of 1000 rows with 7 columns. Scrolling works just fine, so I believe browser is able to handle it fast.

Looks like the problem is that when one types filter text method Grid.refresh() is called, which renders all the rows again and again inserting them as one huge HTML String.

Is there a way to make it more efficient? For instance, I would think that hiding elements in existing html that contains unfiltered set of rows would be faster.

Another way is to somehow cache or delay creation of components in the Grid, but I can't find any row caching capabilities in the GXT Grid API. Maybe I overlooked it.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The caching capability is not found in the `Grid` API itself but in the `GridView`. Grids have a view attribute that you can set.

What version of GXT are you using? In GXT 2.x, there is view variant called `BufferView`.

From documentation:

> Renders the rows as they scroll into view. This GridView is fast for displaying many rows at once, but it does not support all features the normal {link @GridView} supports, such has expanding rows.

If you are using GXT 3.x, you may have to use `LiveGridView` instead because they have removed `BufferView`.

From this, you can specify the cache size, scroll delay, etc.

I hope this helps!

- Paul

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up using LiveGridView with local custom made cached store, so it doesn't go to server every time keeping all the data on the client, but takes advantage of LiveGridView's limited number of cells rendered at the same time.